# Are there any alternatives to Azuon?

Tags: flight-search-engines

Until early October, the [Azuon](http://azuon.com/) tool was worth the subscription fee to me.  But it has been non-functional since then.  Former use: put in an entire country for origin, box populates with all the airports in the country. Same for destination. Put in earliest date, latest date (any two). Click “search” and wait five minutes or more and see a table of five hundred flights with accurate fares. Pick one and book it. NOW, it says NOBODY flies from USA to Taiwan or Europe or Korea, and only Southwest flies within North America. Skyscanner, for comparison, makes you pick one origin and destination before estimating prices, and then a specific date to find the real price.

Anyone familiar with Azuon and aware of something similar?

Yes, Skyscanner is similar, but not close in value, primarily because it makes you select a single origin and destination before it shows prices, and those prices are always very inaccurate estimates.

azair.com is closer, but it doesn't know some airports exist, its user-interface is clumsy, and it often complains that some problem prevented it returning results.

Updates: Azuon has made some bug fixes and some of the problems have gone away.  But it still said "no fares found" for any Korean airport to any US airport for the entire month of March.  As for AzAir.com, yesterday it offered me a dozen flights USA to Spain for $1.99 !! (Of course, they all got error messages from the actual airline.)

Well, I guess the answer is either go back to the old method of spending a hundred dollars worth of time to save a hundred fifty; or just hire someone like chimpando.  I may give the latter a test run.

Comment: So what features exactly did it have that you're missing now?

Comment: All of them.  Former use: put in an entire country for origin, box populates with all the airports in the country.  Same for destination.  Put in earliest date, latest date (any two).  Click “search” and wait five minutes or more and see a table of five hundred flights with _accurate_ fares.  Pick one and book it.  NOW, it says NOBODY flies from USA to Taiwan or Europe or Korea, and only Southwest flies within North America. Skyscanner, for comparison, makes you pick one origin and destination before estimating prices, and then a specific date to find the real price.

Comment: Anyone who wants a better idea of what the tool is _supposed_ to do, can download it free and try it without a subscription.  It hides some of the flight details in that mode, but all the possible settings are visible.

Comment: Maybe contact Azuon to fix things on their end?

Comment: They claim it was due to having to take a month to restore the data from a failed hard disk in a RAID.  I pointed out (1) if that takes more than ten minutes, the RAID is not working and (2) why is it still not working after they claim everything is restored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently the answer is no.

Azuon's latest edition is **much** better than when I posted the question, but still not what it used to be.

So a search that would take less than a half-hour before it broke now takes several hours using my previous methods.

I guess chimpando or similar will definitely have to be tried.

Comment: Came across glowing reviews of Indie.Bootsnall.com so I tried it.  Nice user interface, but not nearly as flexible as Matrix or Azuon.  Also, I tried it on three routes I had already done the hard way, and putting all three together, its best recommendation was $700+ higher.  Meaning my twenty hours of work was worth forty dollars an hour.  Kiwi and TUIFly can do some of what Azuon does.